# SQL - Contacts, Companies DB Design

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, contacts

[image: Basic DB Design]

Im working on a db to manage customer data for a small company.The customers are companies and institutions (schools..etc) and of course people/contacts. There will be a lot more scope added in time, but right now I'm looking for any input on the core design itself and if there's anything I'm missing here that could cause issues down the road. The image doesn't include the additional lookup tables for items like; country, teltype..etc. I'm kinda worried that I've over-normalised it and it is going to make the queries much more complicated in the long-term. Any input appreciated.

Update - 13/12/2016

I have since created a superclass in my structure called entity, which helps me merge all 3 into one as such. I'm still working on the rest as it has grown quite a lot today, so again any input is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You may or may not overthinking the phone, email & location. Would contact have multiple location? Is it beneficial to link contacts that are living on the same address? If not, you might want to put location details on the same table. Same goes for phone & email. Also, even if an institution/company/contact have multiple email/phone, you'll want additional field to mark them as the preferred email/phone for sending message/calling.

Comment: May I ask which tool did you use to design this?

Comment: @Martheen +1 on the preferred suggestion.

Comment: @KamilG. It's an online tool dbdesigner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first impression I get looking at the diagram is that you have over-normalised the data (unless that was your aim).

Consider the Company <-> Telephone relationship you have created:-

[image: CompanyTelephone Relationship]

Creating a relationship like this reads:

> - A Company can have one to many Telephone Numbers
> - A Telephone Number can belong to one to many Companies

Evaluating this for a minute; is it likely that a telephone number is shared by more than one Company in your structure? (real-world suggests it wouldn't)

Expanding upon this, I believe the main reason you may have headed down this course would be to allow the same telephone number to apply to one or many contacts as well as a business?

Personally, in my experience, I would suggest a duplication of data (telephone number) maybe easier to maintain and manage from a development perspective. This will make you data structure and application logic less complex, and should make searching less taxing on the system.

However, it will also mean you could end up with stale data, for example, if all of your contacts used the company phone number and the company number was updated, all of the contacts data would now need updating too.

One way round that from an application perspective would be to display the company number with a company contact, then you would not need to duplicate data.

Here is an example of a de-normalised view of this relationship:

[image: Example]

You could also apply this to email addresses, where the same concept applies.

Comment: Yes, I think you're correct here, I have over normalised it. Looking at your suggestion, it's what I initially drew out but went too far in consolidating the tables, so I created many to many relationships where they're not actually needed and 1 to many would suit better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to have bridge tables for telephone, email, and location? If there is no need to have multiple sites, e-mails, or telephone numbers; you can add the attributes to the primary entity.

Comment: I do need to accommodate for multiple emails/telephones/locations for the future, but the bridge tables weren't a good fit here either.